# Observations of a variable with strings to be numbered based on unique strings in R

Tags: r, string

A column variable with around 64000 observations having strings (with repetitions), I need to number the unique strings in the observations

For Eg refer to attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIrwu.png)

Numbering should be based on Material column, 
for eg:

- Computer = 1
- Keyboard = 2
- Mouse = 3
- Monitor = 4
- USB Port = 5
- Pen = 6
- Paper = 7

Numbers to be pasted on another column

It has to be dynamic, so that even if the list gets increased with another unique Material name, autonumbering should happen

Comment: Images of data are not useful. Please read [mcve]

Comment: The rest of the columns will have the details of the dates of the material requested, purchase order creation, material received, material authentication, invoice generation, payment. Thought it might not be relevant here. Its a 64000 rows and 18 columns of data. IC refers to independent Company, BU refers to business unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Since you didn't provide an easily reproducible dataset, here's a simple one:
> df <- data.frame(Material = c('Keyboard', 'Mouse', 'Keyboard', 'USB', 'USB'))
> df
  Material
1 Keyboard
2    Mouse
3 Keyboard
4      USB
5      USB
```

You can use the `match` function to find the index in a unique subset of the materials, thus providing each material a unique id:

```
> df$mat.id <- match(df$Material, unique(df$Material))
> df
  Material mat.id
1 Keyboard      1
2    Mouse      2
3 Keyboard      1
4      USB      3
5      USB      3
```